How to avoid LIKE in oracle SQL statement
I have following table



ID
Company




1.
892,8392,489,923


2.
232,9238,9283


3.
682,7292



I am able to get the results using following SQL statetment
SELECT *
FROM   company_details
WHERE  company LIKE '%892%' -- Company is Parameter

SELECT *
FROM   company_details
WHERE  company LIKE '%682%' -- Company is parameter

However; I would like to avoid LIKE operator in oracle SQL statement. In this case, how to can I avoid LIKE operator when parameter value could be anything in the company column.

What are those values? IDs? In that case the real solution is to stop storing them as comma separated values. That violates the most basic design rule. Use separate rows, add proper indexes and the query speed will be several orders of magnitude faster. Anything else requires scanning the entire table to extract the values and check whether one of them matches or not

Why do you want to avoid LIKE? As far as I know, it's the standard way to do wildcard queries.

Is that Company column supposed to contain a comma separated list of numbers, where you want an exact match for one number?

HI did you try using  WHERE company Not null ?

Break out your list into separate rows in a child table (normalization). A list in a single column is a violation of first normal form and causes all kinds of grief in a relational database. Then the problem will go away.

@ndc85430 this isn't a wildcard search and LIKE has serious issues here. What if there's 8926 in the middle of the string? You can't use %,892,% either, the string may be at the start or end of the text. This is a bad design

If you don't like data normalization, then you can use any NoSQL database instead of a relational database.

As you were already told, normalization is your best option.
If you can't do it for some reason, here are a few options you might want to consider, try and see whether any of them works OK. Basically, it depends on how large data set is; in a small sample table, every one of them returns desired result. This is a SQL*Plus example so I used substitution variable.
Sample data:
SQL> select * from company_details;

        ID COMPANY
---------- ----------------
         1 892,8392,489,923
         2 232,9238,9283
         3 682,7292

The first option uses like, modified so that leading and trailing commas are appended to cover any value position:
SQL> select * from company_details
  2  where ',' || company || ',' like '%,' || '&par_company' || ',%';
Enter value for par_company: 923

        ID COMPANY
---------- ----------------
         1 892,8392,489,923

SQL> /
Enter value for par_company: 682

        ID COMPANY
---------- ----------------
         3 682,7292

SQL>


The second option normalizes data you currently have, splitting comma-separated list of values into rows:
SQL> create or replace view v_company_details as
  2    select id,
  3           regexp_substr(company, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) company,
  4           column_value rn
  5    from company_details cross join
  6      table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  7                          connect by level <= regexp_count(company, ',') + 1
  8                         ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

View created.

SQL> select * from v_company_details order by id, rn;

        ID COMPANY            RN
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 892                 1
         1 8392                2
         1 489                 3
         1 923                 4
         2 232                 1
         2 9238                2
         2 9283                3
         3 682                 1
         3 7292                2

9 rows selected.

SQL>

Now, you can join that view to the original table:
SQL> select * from company_details
  2  where id in (select id
  3               from v_company_details
  4               where company = '&par_company'
  5              );
Enter value for par_company: 923

        ID COMPANY
---------- ------------------------------
         1 892,8392,489,923

SQL> /
Enter value for par_company: 682

        ID COMPANY
---------- ------------------------------
         3 682,7292

SQL>

Or, use only the view, this time by aggregating companies (beware of listagg's length limit, though):
SQL> select id, listagg(company, ',') within group (order by rn) company
  2  from v_company_details
  3  where id in (select id from v_company_details
  4               where company = '&par_company'
  5              )
  6  group by id;
Enter value for par_company: 923

        ID COMPANY
---------- ------------------------------
         1 892,8392,489,923

SQL> /
Enter value for par_company: 682

        ID COMPANY
---------- ------------------------------
         3 682,7292

SQL>


Someone else might suggest other options; as I said, pick the one that suits you the best.

Convert to JSON and use json_table or json_exists. Maybe even convert the entire column and index it. Not as good as a separate table but better than parsing the entire table every time

Change your table and only store a single company in each row:
CREATE TABLE company_details (
  id      NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
  company NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT company_details__id__comp__u UNIQUE (id, company)
);

INSERT INTO company_details (id, company) VALUES (1,892);
INSERT INTO company_details (id, company) VALUES (1,8392);
INSERT INTO company_details (id, company) VALUES (1,489);
INSERT INTO company_details (id, company) VALUES (1,923);
INSERT INTO company_details (id, company) VALUES (2,232);
INSERT INTO company_details (id, company) VALUES (2,9238);
INSERT INTO company_details (id, company) VALUES (2,9283);
INSERT INTO company_details (id, company) VALUES (3,682);
INSERT INTO company_details (id, company) VALUES (3,7292);

Then:

The data will be normalised;

You can add indexes; and

Easily search for individual items in the company column.
SELECT *
FROM   company_details
WHERE  company = 892;

Which outputs:



ID
COMPANY




1
892






If you want to display the list of companies then you can do that too using LISTAGG.
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(company, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY company) AS company
FROM   company_details
GROUP BY id

Which outputs:



ID
COMPANY




1
489,892,923,8392


2
232,9238,9283


3
682,7292



and if you want to find the full details of where company = 892:
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(company, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY company) AS company
FROM   company_details
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(CASE company WHEN 892 THEN 1 END) > 0;

Which outputs:



ID
COMPANY




1
489,892,923,8392



fiddle

You can use the REGEXP_LIKE function instead of the LIKE operator. REGEXP_LIKE allows the use of regular expressions.
SELECT * FROM company_details WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(company, '(^|,)' || :company || '(,|$)');

:company = 892 or other

That just covers the real bug, forcing a full table scan

That is correct, it is viable for tables with few rows, since in tables with a lot of data it is inefficient. Basically the solution is to take as an example the table with the rows shown below.

What happens if that table is used in a larger query? The lack of indexes and statistics will force the database to create an inefficient execution plan for the entire query.
